# Call function on div click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am doing this: `<div onclick='alert("xxx")'>Click me!</div>` and I see that alert but I want to call on function inside that `onclick`.
I'm trying this but it doesn't work.

```
  function GetContent(prm){
    alert(prm);
  }

  <div onclick='GetContent("xxx")'>Click me!</div>
```

**I need to call that function inline not assign an id or class to that div and use jQuery.** What is the solution?

Comment: jQuery is used exactly to remove the inline function which dont degrade well in the absence of javascript

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using code `inline` is bad practice, you need to assign an `ID` or `Class` to the div and call function against it eg:

```
<div class="test">Click me!</div>

$('div.test').click(function(){
    GetContent("xxx");
});
```

.

> I need to call that function inline
>   not assign an id or class to that div
>   and use jquery.

I think you are already doing that with this code:

```
<div onclick='GetContent("xxx")'>Click me!</div>
```

Calling function inline without assigning id or class. But as said before, it is not good practice to use inline code.

Answer (score 5):

You can give that div a class and then do something like this

```
$("div.myclass").click(function(){
    GetContent("xxx");
});

<div class="myclass"></div>
```

This will fire click event to all div elements with class 'myclass'.

But I am not sure why you don't want to give an id to the div element.